# При попытке вывести код сайта UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2'

Tags: python

Хочу вывести содержимое сайта

```
import requests    
source = requests.get('https://vk.com/powerdrill')
print(source.text)
```

Интерпретатор ругается

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 4678-4678: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

В чем дело ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно вы в IDLE или другой Python REPL, использующей Tkinter для создания GUI, пользуетесь.

Как сообщение об ошибке говорит,  Tk не поддерживает не BMP символы (Unicode символы с номером больше 0xffff)—смайлики часто в этой категории находятся.

Чтобы обойти ошибку, запустите ваш Питон скрипт вне IDLE. Или если хотите печатать в IDLE такие строки для отладки, то экранируйте BMP-символы, к примеру `print(ascii(text))`, тогда  как `'\U0001f602'` будет показан.